# Spring Security - Ensure PreAuthorize PermitAll allows access without custom config class

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a code sample at: 
https://github.com/vicsz/pcf-sso-resource-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/pcfssoresourceexample/WebController.java

Is there a way to the get the *PreAuthorize PermitAll* annotation to allow all access (including no security) ? Specifically WITHOUT writing a custom configuration class extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ?

Comment: If you use Spring Boot's default configuration, all URLs are protected except some static sources. Hence, the answer is: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment from @dur ... it can't be done.